# Liouville function and perfect squares for Gaussian integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\lambda$ be the [Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function). It is a well known fact that the characteristic function of the perfect squares, denoted by $\chi_2$, can be written as $\chi_2(n)=\sum_{d|n}\lambda(d)$. My question is there an analogous for the  characteristic function of perfect [Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) squares and the Liouville function for Gaussian integers?

Comment: A Gaussian Liouville function is defined by Borwein and Coons in Transcendence of the Gaussian Liouville number amd relatives, available at http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~pborwein/PAPERS/P230.pdf (but I don't think that paper discusses the particular question of interest here).